# Color Terminal Error in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've just installed jupyter in my other terminal and I'm getting this error when I'm opening it.

```
n _log_default
    _log_formatter = self._log_formatter_cls(fmt=self.log_format, datefmt=self.log_datefmt)
  File "c:\users\jcajandi\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tornado\log.py", line 154, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("No supported color terminal library")
RuntimeError: No supported color terminal library
```

Can you help me fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
There is an error of Tornado 4.5.
Installing the previous package, **Tornado 4.4.3**, please.

```
pip install tornado==4.4.3
```

Comment: Hi, Ivan! Yes, this is caused by the new Tornado. There is actuallly another one who asked this question maybe after an hour after I've asked. That's where I got the answer.